# How to increase the width of a SharePoint Online List column within a List WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to increase the width of a SharePoint Online List column within a List Web Part. When I simply increase the width of a column in the List, other users do not see the change. So, I tried formatting the column (one single line, the other multi-line) by using JSON (see below) but this does not extend as far as we want (currently only seems to extend about 350 px). Does any one know what we can do to increase our List column width so all users will see it when the List Part loads on the page?

{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": {
"width": "750px",
"font-size": "14px"
}
}

We cannot get anything to work, looking at below what would be recommended to increase the width of the 'Name' column?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JSON format can not achieve this.It can only change inner div style.
[image]

You could use spfx extension to inject css file change outer div style.
Example:https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss

Comment: please see additional information added regarding question on recommendations on what we could do to increase the width.